# How do I recompile an Elixir project and reload it from within iex?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I'm currently learning Elixir by going through the OTP and mix tutorial on the elixir-lang website, and I'm having trouble finding out how to recompile and reload the project from within the shell.

In Erlang I would do `make:all([load])` and it would compile and load any changes that occurred.  However, in `iex` that always says `:up_to_date`, which does make sense, as Elixir uses mix for it's compiling needs.

I can't find any equivalent from within iex.

Comment: Did you try `r/1` in `iex`? Note that you can invoke a help in `iex` by calling `h()`. See around if some of that can help you.

Comment: I hadn't known about `r/1` but that still isn't equivalent.  I have to manually enter each module I have updated code for where as `make:all([load])` would auto-detect updated modules and recompile/reload them.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540703/make-elixir-app-recompile-and-reload-on-source-code-change and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-lang-talk/uU8K2NJAE70? It seems that this is duplicated with those one.

Comment: I was wondering the same and I decided to develop [lettuce](https://github.com/gilacost/lettuce). It is a gen server that watches your files and recompiles the project for you without leaving the IEx. Check it out !

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can use the [`IEx.Helpers.recompile/0`](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.Helpers.html#recompile/0) function.

> Recompiles the current Mix application.
>
> This helper only works when IEx is started with a Mix project, for
>   example, `iex -S mix`. Before compiling the code, it will stop the
>   current application, and start it again afterwards. Stopping
>   applications are required so processes in the supervision tree won't
>   crash when code is upgraded multiple times without going through the
>   proper hot-code swapping mechanism.
>
> Changes to `mix.exs` or configuration files won't be picked up by this
>   helper, only changes to sources. Restarting the shell and Mix is
>   required in such cases.
>
> If you want to reload a single module, consider using `r ModuleName`
>   instead.
>
> NOTE: This feature is experimental and may be removed in upcoming
>   releases.

From https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.2.4/lib/iex/lib/iex/helpers.ex#L56-L93

Comment: Would `c("filename.ex")` work the same way @Dogbert? Just curious.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci no, it just recompiles a file, period.

Comment: IEx.Helpers.recompile/0 will crash running processes. It will also ignore compile errors by not loading the failed modules.  This makes it unusable for live coding.

Comment: The behaviour of this function has changed - it no longer restarts the application. Also, the documentation has moved and is now [here](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.Helpers.html#recompile/0).

Answer (score 24):

February 26, 2017:

To hot load components in a running elixir system with the lowest chance of something going wrong use:

```
case c(filename_ex, :in_memory) do
    [] -> :ignore
    [mod|_] -> r(mod)
end
```

Original answer:

In elixir 1.3.0 recompile does not restart the application anymore. So the correct way to check if any source changed and hotload is:

```
iex> recompile()
```

NOTE: I want to add that due to issues with removing modules during the recompile you will most likely crash processes while the recompile is occurring if you have in flight messages like a gen_statem with a state_timeout.

NOTE2: Using recompile/0 if you make an error in a source file, the project will compile with that source file missing and unloaded.

Answer (score 8):

The one downside to @Dogbert's answer I found is it does a complete stop and restart of the application.  While this is ok in theory it failed in my current project as my project dependend on Ranch, but everything didn't get stopped properly.  This meant things broke when it tried to restart the project it failed because the socket was already in use.

Long story short, I looked at the helper's code and added the following function to my module:

```
  def recompile() do
    Mix.Task.reenable("app.start")
    Mix.Task.reenable("compile")
    Mix.Task.reenable("compile.all")
    compilers = Mix.compilers
    Enum.each compilers, &Mix.Task.reenable("compile.#{&1}")
    Mix.Task.run("compile.all")
  end
```

Now I can enter `MyApp.recompile` and everything is hot-reloaded without the application restarting.

Comment: This is no longer working in version 1.5. I get `[:noop, :noop]`